# Fit a quadratic form given covariant derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a slightly simpler variant of a question I already asked, but the setup is different enough that it can't be solved the same way.  Suppose we have a quadratic form:

$f(x) = x^T Q x$

and for a known $x$ we know the projection of $Qx$ orthogonal to $x$, that is:

$(I-xx^T)Qx$

and we also know

$(I-xx^T)Q(I-xx^T) - (x^TQx)(I-xx^T)$

How do we solve for $Q$?

---

Given the question as I originally phrased it is nearly trivial, consider the extension where $x^TQx$ is not known, only $(I-xx^T)Qx$ and $(I-xx^T)Q(I-xx^T) - (x^TQx)(I-xx^T)$ are known.

Comment: Right, it actually turns out to be almost trivial.

Let $g = (I-xx^T)Qx$, let $h = (I-xx^T)Q(I-xx^T)-(x^TQx)(I-xx^T)$.  You can expand $Q$ as $(I-xx^T)Q(I-xx^T) + xx^TQ(I-xx^T) + (I-xx^T)Qxx^T + xx^TQxx^t = h + xg^T + gx^T + f(x).$

Answer (score 1):

In your revised setting, there isn't sufficient to back out $Q$. For example, consider the following $2\times2$ case:
\begin{align*}
Q&=\begin{pmatrix}q_{11}&q_{12}\\q_{21}&q_{22}\end{pmatrix},\\
x&=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},\\
(I-xx^T)Qx&=\begin{pmatrix}0\\q_{21}\end{pmatrix},\\
(I-xx^T)Q(I-xx^T) - (x^TQx)(I-xx^T)&=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&q_{22}-q_{11}\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
In this case, we know the difference between the diagonal entries $q_{22}$ and $q_{11}$, but we cannot determine $q_{11}$ and $q_{22}$ individually.

Comment: OK, so say we can solve for Q up to some constant factor on the diagonal.  That means we could still solve for the eigenvectors of Q, right?

Comment: @DavidPfau If $Q$ is symmetric and $x$ is a unit vector, it seems so.